# How can I use java streams to retrieve the value of x names?

Tags: java, java-8

I can use the below snippet to retrieve the name if there is 1 entry in the list by retrieving element 0 in the list, however, each `NameResponse` can have several names (e.g. a first name, a middle name and a surname). How can I retrieve x names associated with one customer? There could be 20 names for argument's sake. I would like to implement using a stream since I am using Java 8, but I am unsure how to implement this. Any suggestions?

```
private List<String> getNames(Customer customer) {

    List<NameResponse> nameResponses = new ArrayList<>();
    NameResponse nameResponse = new NameResponse();
    nameResponse.setName("Test Name");
    nameResponses.add(nameResponse);
    customer.setNames(nameResponses);

    return List.of(customer.getNames().get(0).getName());
}
```

Customer class:

```
private List<NameResponse> names;
```

NameResponse class:

```
private String name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like below assuming you have the appropriate getters:

```
return customer.getNames()
               .stream()
               .map(NameResponse::getName)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do that using the [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) operator on the stream and then collect to output a list:

```
return customer.getNames().stream()
    .map(nameResponse -> nameResponse.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: I could have accepted either answer, both do the same just your has the lambda and the other has method reference! Thanks